# How to expand and compute log(a + b)?

Tags: math, logarithm

I would like to know the complete expansion of `log(a + b)`.

For example

```
log(a * b) = log(a) + log(b);
log(a / b) = log(a) - log(b);
```

Similar to this, is there any expansion for log(a + b)?

Comment: Belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Per @mahonya’s comment: Scipy provides a [`scipy.misc.logsumexp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.logsumexp.html) that might be very useful if you can get `log(a)` and `log(b)`!

Comment: This post is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403529/9513184).

Comment: This is the closest math.stackexchange duplicate I could find: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734228/separating-the-log-of-a-sum

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In general, one doesn't expand out `log(a + b)`; you just deal with it as is.  That said, there are occasionally circumstances where it makes sense to use the following identity:

```
log(a + b) = log(a * (1 + b/a)) = log a + log(1 + b/a)
```

(In fact, this identity is often used when implementing `log` in math libraries).